# Universal Brotherhood in 2075

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, campaign

Do you think there is many changes to make in the storyline to move the Universal Brotherhood campaign (and events directly related to it, like the Chicago city destruction) from ~2050 to the basic 2075 settings of Shadowrun 5 ?

I have players who don't know the universe at all, so no problem on this side, but i don't really see what problems this modification can cause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only a handful of things that this might impact.

The spell 'Insecticide' from the Street Grimoire was developed after the initial Bug City incident

The Bug City incident was the big trigger behind the massive fear and paranoia around Bug Spirits that exists in modern Shadowrun....but that's pure fluff and can easily be ignored.

Likewise, in terms of fluff, Ares Reputation took something of a hit when it was discovered that FAB Strain III targeted anything that was astrally active, and thus killed a bunch of ghouls.

Other than that...while the events of the Bug City may have had an impact on the overall cultural climate of the world...it didn't *directly* impact very many things. You should be able to make this shift pretty easily if you want your players to get to experience the fall of Chicago.

Comment: One would expect that killing ghouls would be a good thing.

Comment: @ShadowKras Shadowrun ghouls are not other-fantasy-setting ghouls. By the 2070s, ghouls are more thoroughly recognized as people-with-a-disease. Of course, part of that recognition came due to what happened in Bug City, when Ares FAB-III slaughtered a bunch of them, purely because they had the misfortune to be trapped in Chicago when the walls went up.

Comment: @T.J.L. I know that. But even though Asamando is recognized by the corporate court, it isn't by the UN. There is the whole *1% of your body weight in raw human meat per week* cannibalism thing.

Comment: @ShadowKras Right, as so there's this big push to find a synthetic substitute so that these 'Poor sick people' can rejoin society as a whole. And so the Corp that invents this substitute can make craptons of nuyen. I mean, if nothing else...between Ghouls and Gnashers, the corps have a new corpse-disposal system that is more efficient than pigs! (yay dystopia)